# Can't create keys for an NFT. cardano-cli address key-gen

Tags: nft

Having trouble create a key for an nft.

Code:

```
cardano-cli address key-gen \
 --verification-key-file payment.vkey \
 --signing-key-file payment.skey
```

Error:

```
error: Found argument 'address' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: can you show the output of `cardano-cli --version` ?

Comment: I'm getting the same error for cardano-cli version: 1.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Do not build/use the client from https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-cli

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your cardano-cli version is up to date, if you are typing in the command exactly as typed above, you will need to escape the line breaks like so:

```
cardano-cli address key-gen \
  --verification-key-file payment.vkey \
  --signing-key-file payment.skey
```

Comment: that was my first thought, but that doesnt lead to this error message